# Riemann integrable function on [a, b] which is not monotonic [a, b].

Tags: functions, riemann-integration, monotone-functions

I need to find a Riemann integrable function, which is not monotonic on a closed interval. But I couldn't find one. I checked some continuous and discontinuous functions but still couldn't find a function satisfying the above things.

Can anyone give an example for Riemann integrable function, which is not monotonic on a closed interval?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand.  $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: $\sin(x)$ over the interval $[-2\pi,2\pi]?$

Comment: I mean, by probability you could pick a continuous function at random and succeed nearly 100% of the time.  You must be misphrasing the problem.

Comment: Do you mean that there is **no** interval on which the function is monotonic?  That would be a more interesting problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean a function that is not monotonic *anywhere*, but still integrable, there is the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function), which is continuous everywhere (and thus integrable everywhere), but is nowhere monotonic.

[image: Weierstrass function]

Answer (score 2):

My favorite nowhere-differentiable continuous $f:[0,1]\to [0,1].$

Take the uniform limit $g$ of a sequence $(g_n:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of continuous functions,

where, for each $n$ and for any $a,b\in\Bbb N_0$ with $a<2^n$ and $b<2^n,$

there exists $t\in \Bbb N_0$ with $t<4^n,$ such that for all $n'\ge n,\;$ $\;g_{n'}$ maps $[t4^{-n},(t+1)4^{-n}]$ into $[(a2^{-n},(a+1)2^{-n}]\times [b2^{-n},(b+1)2^{-n}].$

Then $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ is the Peano-Hilbert space-filling curve.

For $g(t)=(x,y)$, let $f(t)=x.$ Then $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ is a continuous surjection. Now $f$ is not constant on any interval $J
\subset [0,1]$ of non-zero length but for any $t\in J,$ the set $\{t'\in J: f(t')=f(t)\}$ is uncountable, so $f$ cannot be monotonic on $J.$